# How can I copy-paste rotated sections of canvas without overlap or multiple canvases?

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, html5-canvas

Say I have a canvas, and on that canvas I have a clip/path/drawing that is the shape of a pizza slice (triangle with one side rounded). I want to duplicate these slices and put them on the canvas so that their points touch. It is like I have one of these triagle/slices, and I want to make this:

[image]

The center of the pizza is in the center of the canvas, if that makes anything more convenient. I could also make the number of slices 8, so that 3 translations/flips would do the trick.

Multiple canvases is OK if necessary, but I would think there is an easy way to do this that I am just not thinking of.

I have some code started here (sorry its in coffeescript), but it is not much: http://jsbin.com/qobogeponu/1/edit?html,js,output

Responses in JS are just as welcome.

Any clues on how to flip an image over an axis, or rotate image data, or anything you think might be of help, would be appreciated. Thank you for your time!

Bonus points: I would like every other slice to be flipped along an axis drawn from the center of the pizza through the middle of the slice.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is to just add a circle (full arc) and the four lines needed. When strokes this has good performance.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    r = 190,
    pi2 = Math.PI*2,
    slices = 8,
    slice = pi2 / slices;

ctx.translate(200.5, 200.5); // center (+0.5 to make sharper)
ctx.arc(0, 0, r, 0, 2*Math.PI);

for(var i = 0; i < slices*0.5; i++) {  // count only 4 lines
  ctx.moveTo(r*Math.cos(slice*i), r*Math.sin(slice*i));
  ctx.lineTo(-r*Math.cos(slice*i), -r*Math.sin(slice*i));
}

ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

The other technique is to have a sub-function creating a single slice. This is useful if you need to hover or click it at some point as you can regenerate the path and use `isPointInPath()` to check if mouse position is inside, and recolor etc.

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
    r = 190,
    pi2 = Math.PI*2,
    slices = 8,
    slice = pi2 / slices;

ctx.beginPath(); // important when redrawing all, or checking for one slice

for(var i = 0; i < slices; i++) drawSlice(i);  // all slices added to path

ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.stroke();

// in this demo the function uses global, you can parametrize those if wanted
function drawSlice(index) {
  ctx.translate(canvas.width  * 0.5 + 0.5,
                canvas.height * 0.5 + 0.5); // center (+0.5 to make sharper)
  ctx.rotate(index * slice);                // rotate accord. slice index
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0);                         // line start in center
  ctx.lineTo(r, 0);                         // to edge
  ctx.arc(0, 0, r, 0, slice);               // arc angle for one slice
  ctx.closePath();                          // line back to center and close

  ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);            // reset all transforms
}

ctx.fillStyle = "gold";

canvas.onmousemove = function(e) {
  
  var r = canvas.getBoundingClientRect(),   // correct the mouse pos
      x = e.clientX - r.left,
      y = e.clientY - r.top;
  
  for(var i = 0; i < slices; i++) {         // check each slice
    ctx.beginPath();                        // we need each single slice
    drawSlice(i);                           // add the slice to path
    if (ctx.isPointInPath(x, y)) {          // inside the path?
      ctx.fill();                           // fill/stroke for demo
      ctx.stroke();
    }
  }
};
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

Just be aware of that with the latter technique the edges are over-drawn twice which may produce a little harder edge. You would need to skip one edge to avoid this. I leave it as an exercise for OP to do that. :)

**Update**: Now, as to flipping, mirroring etc. This is usually known as a classic performant technique, however, since you anyways need to draw at least one quarter of the circle using path, stroke it etc., to have a basis to mirror (as we don't have access to low-level implementation of the bitmap, nor can be compile the code at will, make it work on GPU and so on..) the question becomes if it is really *faster* to flip copy as this will require addition calls from JS versus stroking using browser's internals in compiled code.

It can be done though:

```js
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"),
  r = 190,
  pi2 = Math.PI * 2,
  slices = 8,
  slice = pi2 / slices;

ctx.beginPath(); // important when redrawing all, or checking for one slice

for (var i = 0; i < 2; i++) drawSlice(i); // all slices added to path

ctx.lineJoin = "round"; // avoid "spikes"
ctx.lineWidth = 8;
ctx.stroke();

ctx.scale(-1, 1); // mirror canvas hor.
ctx.translate(-canvas.width, 0); // move origin to other edge
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);    // draw hortizontal mirror
ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0);  // reset matrix

ctx.scale(1, -1); // mirror canvas vert.
ctx.translate(0, -canvas.height); // move origin to other edge
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0, 0);    // draw hortizontal mirror


// in this demo the function uses global, you can parametrize those if wanted
function drawSlice(index) {
  ctx.translate(canvas.width * 0.5 + 0.5,
    canvas.height * 0.5 + 0.5); // center (+0.5 to make sharper)
  ctx.rotate(index * slice); // rotate accord. slice index
  ctx.moveTo(0, 0); // line start in center
  ctx.lineTo(r, 0); // to edge
  ctx.arc(0, 0, r, 0, slice); // arc angle for one slice
  ctx.closePath(); // line back to center and close

  ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // reset all transforms
}
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400></canvas>
```

You *can* use `setTransform()` to set both scale and translation in one line, but I showed them separately so it's easier to see what goes on.